# I'm working in netbeans trying to read data from a file and displaying it but it seems to be printing only some lines

Tags: java, netbeans, filereader

here is the code

```
//import java.util.*;
package javaapplication8;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.*;

public class JavaApplication8 {

public static void main(String[] args) //throws Exception
{
    try{
        FileReader file = new FileReader("C:/Users/Rand/Desktop/fort.txt");
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
     String abc;
     while(reader.readLine() != null)
     {
         abc = reader.readLine();
         System.out.println(abc);
     }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
            {
                   System.out.println( e);
            }

}
}
```

Content of the input file:

> im dieing to get away
>   let the pain of yesterday go slippin through these cracks...
>   hidin myself away

Output:

> let the pain of yesterday go slippin through these cracks...

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `readLine` twice at each iteration - amend your code to:

```
String abc;
while((abc = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(abc);
}
```

or using a slightly different syntax that makes the scope of `abc` narrower:

```
for (String abc; (abc = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
  System.out.println(abc);
}
```

Comment: I was just about to post this, you beat me to it

Comment: the question or the answer?